# Cramps/pain in feet and toes after turbo trainer rides and cyclocross races

Tags: shoes

Recently I purchased a pair of mtb shoes one size larger than I needed (due to lack of availability and time), sizes I needed: uk 11 the size I purchased: uk 12.

After a turbo trainer rides or cyclocross race I have cramps/pain in feet and toes.

Should I replace the shoes or could it be something else?

Comment: It could be something else, but Occam's Razor suggests it's the shoes, especially if nothing else has changed.

Comment: You should replace the shoes *and* it could be something else! Can you not rule in/out other causes based on when you bought the shoes and when the pain started?

Comment: Sorry I should have added in the question that I have never felt this kind of pain with other shoes that I have had in the past, just in case anyone has had a similar problem that went away with say a cleat position change.

Comment: Have you previously done that much riding in that short of a time-span?

Comment: yes been riding for about 3 years now.

Comment: I think this page on quora might have answered my question: http://www.quora.com/Cycling/What-causes-foot-pain-cramping-while-wearing-new-clipless-cycling-shoes

Comment: Is there any chance you could summarise that link and submit it as an answer? It's just that I can't see the solution without registering on the Quora site, which I don't really want to have to do. It'll make the question a bit more complete if someone else on here has the same problem. There's no problem on here if you answer your own questions. Cheers.

Comment: My guess is that the effective cleat position is wrong for your feet, probably too far forward, assuming your feet ride all the way back in the shoes.

Comment: I've fixed a lot of discomfort issues with my shoes by adjusting the cleat position. I had to size up my winter shoes and due to the larger size, I had to move my cleats forward a bit because I was having some discomfort.

Answer (score 1):

It's almost certainly the shoes but exactly what is a really variable question. New shoe problems tend to fit into the following:

1, Does the shoe fit properly (length and width)? Seems the answer is no as you got a size too big which means your foot will move a bit. This can be mitigated with the correct insole and you can even get mouldable ones which you heat, put in your shoes then put your shoes on.
2, Is the insole right? Loads of shoes come with an "average" insole which doesn't really suit everyone. My road shoes came with 4 sets of inserts to tune the fit properly and it's noticeable when I go back to the cheaper ones. Consider transferring your old insoles if they fit or get some new ones
3, Is the cleat position right? Given the shoe size is wrong, this will be hard to get right just by eye. I tend to take a few hours riding with a pair of shoes to get it approximately right and then maybe another 20-30 hours to get it exactly right. After that I either use the system the shoes use to retain the cleat position when I put new ones on or the low-tech approach of a marker pen.

I'd do 3, then 2 then if that fails and your feet still hurt, get new shoes.